# Будет ли тире "съедать" запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

*Желаю здоровья, счастья и добра, а главное( )удачи.*

Какой же знак тут поставить? Будет ли тире "съедать" запятую?

Comment: Поставить нужно или запятую, или тире. Здесь *а главное* — вводное. 
См. [link text][1]


  [1]: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_136

Comment: Тире, ибо оно обозначает более длинную паузу, чем запятая

Comment: Здесь должно стоять тире (вне всяких сомнений).

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что здесь однозначно должно стоять только тире, потому что после вводного слова "главное" идет пауза, вызванная тем, что налицо неполное предложение (а главное, желаю удачи)

Comment: неполное выделяется тире при наличии паузы. А не наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Желаю здоровья, счастья и добра, а главное( )удачи. Это не простое предложение с однородными членами и вводным словом, а сложносочинённое, второе предложение неполное с пропуском сказуемого, поэтому ставится только тире. К тому же напрашивается указательное слово это: а главное (чего желаю) - это удачи.

Comment: почему "сложность" и "неполнота" отменяют запятую при вводном слове? Я бы поставила оба знака. И, пожалуйста, объясните, ПОЧЕМУ сложное. Я согласна, но доказать не могу.

Comment: Я бы хотел посмотреть на доказательство недоказуемого.  
Грамматика (вернее сказать - её существующая формашизация) не дает возможности однозначно проанализировать такую структуру, можно, конечно, трактовать и как сложное предложение (как и вообще половину случаев побобного перечисления), но зачем? В таких случаях выступает принцип простоты. Чем проще объяснение, тем лучше. Т.е. незачем искать сложносочиненного предложения там, где вполне можно обойтись обнородными членами. А вообще: "не плоди сущностей" (с) *принцип бритвы Оккама*.

Comment: Где Вы видите перечисление? Оно бы было, если б было так:Желаю здоровья, счастья, и добра, и, главное,удачи.Или:Желаю не здоровья, счастья и добра, а главного - удачи(Всё равно было бы тире). А в данном предложении смысл:Желаю здоровья, счастья и добра, а главное -это то, что желаю удачи. Главное - подлежащее неполного предложения с пропуском сказуемого, а не вводное.А насчёт принципа простоты - бывает простота "хуже воровства". Чтобы объяснить пунктуацию, нужно ясно представлять структуру предложения.

Comment: >Желаю здоровья, счастья, и добра, и, главное,удачи.  
  
И так тоже. А если бы было "а еще - здоровья"? Тоже "не перечисление"? Как-то очень витиевато получается, один противительный союз - и весь  синтаксис пересматривать...  
Ладно, мысль понял, хотя не могу согласиться. Мне кажется, считать все это перечислением однородных совсем грамматике не противоречит.

Comment: Жаль, что не можете согласиться, потому что Вы как раз всё чувствуете.И чувствуете, что "а ещё - здоровья" - это уже присоединительная конструкция в виде неполного предложения, потому и поставили тире вместо сказуемого.А упрощённо объясняете для "непосвящённых".Зря, неблагодарное это дело, Вас и обвинят, со мной такое было много раз.Витиеватости здесь нет, как раз вносит ясность,потому что противительный союз здесь относится к глаголу, а не дополнению, это всё меняет. Ряд дополнений-однородные члены, ряд сказуемых в опр.-личном невозможен(в совр. р.я), это несколько односоставных.

Comment: Людмила, я вообще ничего не чувствую в подубных вещах. Еслинственное, что меня профессионально связывает (связывало) с языком, это давнопрошедший период занятий формализацией грамматики в уелях машинного перевода. Как понимаете, образ мысли - сугубо рассудочные, более того - формальный. Все что не имеет формального выражения - не существует. До чувств ли тут?   
Пока не разложено по полочкам "это так потому, что имеет место то-то и то-то", апеллировать у моему пониманию бесполезно. А здесь я не вижу конретного и разумного критерия отнесения предложения к сложным или простым с перечислением.

Answer (score -2):

> Какой же знак тут поставить?

Лучше - тире. Обособление "а главное" тут не смотрится, поскольку на него падает логическое ударение.

> Будет ли тире "съедать" запятую?

Это альтернативные варианты, о "съедании" речи идти не может.

Comment: Очередная фига в кармане.

Comment: Если вы посчитали минус, выставленный другим участником, за мою "фигу", то ошиблись. Ваши ответы читаю по диагонали, только для того, чтобы утвердиться в своем мнении — ваши знания ограничиваются умением быстро осуществлять поиск по Интернету, опыта работы с текстом вы не имеете, серьезных знаний по русскому языку — тоже. Итого: вашим ответам доверять нельзя.

Comment: А что значит - 'не смотрится?' Да еще в качестве главного аргумента? И почему тире в неполном предложении и запятая после вводного слова - это альтернативные знаки?

Comment: Marina-ja, "Фига в кармане" заключалась в том, что её поставили, не сказав ничего. Остальное не комментирую.

**Уважаемый модератор, объективности ради, обратите, наконец, внимание на постоянное провоцировние склоки пользователем Marina-ja**

>А что значит - 'не смотрится?'  
  
Это значит, что приходится выбирать, ориентируясь на восприятие текста. 

>Да еще в качестве главного аргумента. И почему тире в неполном предложении и запятая после вводного слова - это альтернативные знаки?    
         
Я не говорил ни про главный арнумент, ни про неполное предложение.